# I get nothing\blank when trying to output this function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, char

update"he question is asking me to run through str just once and they already given me that the function need to be just with one argument)"
 I am trying to return the first character that doesn't repeat itself, for example: "blazqnqbla"-> the first character that does not repeat itself is "z", so the function needs to return z. now the function takes a string (str) that built from the character which the ASCII values of the character are between 1-127(including 1 and 127).
The problem is I am getting a blank output. I get nothing when trying to output the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
char first(char *str);
char first(char *str){
    int L = 0;
    int a[127] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i<127; i++){
        a[i] = i+1;
    }
    while (str[L] != '\0'){
        for(int d=1; d<127; d++){
            if (str[L]==(char)d){
                if (a[L]>0){
                    a[L] = 0;
                    L++;
                    break;
                }
                else if (a[L]==0){
                    a[L] =- 1;
                    L++;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    L++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<127; i++){
        if(a[i]==0)
            return (char)(i+1);
    }
    return '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "blazqnqbla";
    char m   = first(s);
    printf("%c", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function is very complicated for this problem. Do you need to return the first, or one of the non-repeating characters? But even then, store in a[] how many time the character i was stored, in b[] the first time it appeared and then just loop over a and b to get the minimum of b where a is 1.

Comment: why not just run through str twice? once to  increment a[i] on each appearance and the second time to check if a[i] ==1 and return the first true.

Comment: Is there any constraint for this problem?

Comment: @suvojit_007 yes, the function need to take only one argument(char *str), and need to run\loop through str(string\array) only once.

Comment: Is nested loop allowed here?

Comment: allowd if it not loop through str twice(like what I did in the code)

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry but your function is much too complex. At a point that even you cannot understand it and use `a[L]` when it should be `a[d]`. That would return something but only the first letter in alphabetic order. So in your example it would be `n`.

To make it work, you need:

- an array of all possible chars to note if they were seen never (say 0), once (say > 0), or more than once (say -1).
- an array noting the order in which unique characters have been encountered
- when a char is first encountered, add it in next position in the array for the order, and store that rank in first array.

The code for the function can become:

```
char first(char *str){
    int a[127] = {0};              // rank+1 of the character in resul array
    char resul[127] = {0};         // array of candidates for unique characters
    int rank = 0;                  // current position in array of unique candidates
    char c;
    while((c = *str++) != '\0') {  // scan the input string one char at a time
        int i = (unsigned char) c; // convert to int to avoid warnings when
                                   //  using the char value as an index
        if (c > 127) {             // control char validity
            fprintf(stderr, "Forbidden character %d\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (a[i] == 0) {        // first time seen, store the character
            resul[rank] = c;
            a[i] = rank + 1;    // and its rank
            rank += 1;
        }
        else if (a[i] > 0) {    // already seen, remove it
            resul[a[i] -1] = 0;
            a[i] = -1;          // and never use it any longer
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<127; i++){   // return first unique character
        if(resul[i]!=0)
            return resul[i];
    }
    return '\0';
}
```

In this code, the input string is only scanned once, as is the result array. All other access are directly through an index.

Answer (score 1):

@Broman's implementation is good and recursive.
I include a non-recursive implementation.
Algorithm: Scan the string from begin to end:
If the index of the current character is the same searching from the beginning (strchr) and also from the end (strrchr), then that character is unique.
else, I return '-' if nothing is unique. (This may have to be changed depending on your application)

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char first_unique_char(const char* s);

int main()
{
    char s[] = "abcdefghijtkqyabcdefghijkqx";
    char unique = first_unique_char(s);
    printf("The first unique char is %c\n",
                unique);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
// -----------------------------
char first_unique_char(const char* s)
{
    int i = 0;
    char* loc_forward = NULL;
    char* loc_backward = NULL;
    int len = strlen(s);
    bool found = false;

    printf("Len = %d\n", len);
    for(; i < len; i++)
    {
        loc_backward = strrchr(s, s[i]);
        loc_forward = strchr(s, s[i]);

        printf("i = %d, Char = %c, Loc_rev: %d, Loc_forward %d\n",
                        i, s[i], (int)(loc_backward - s), (int)(loc_forward - s));
        if ((loc_backward - s == i) && (loc_forward - s == i))//unique
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Returning at %d, s[i] = %c\n", i, s[i]);
    if (!found)
        return '-';
    else
        return s[i];
}
```

---

Output:

```
Len = 27
i = 0, Char = a, Loc_rev: 14, Loc_forward 0
i = 1, Char = b, Loc_rev: 15, Loc_forward 1
i = 2, Char = c, Loc_rev: 16, Loc_forward 2
i = 3, Char = d, Loc_rev: 17, Loc_forward 3
i = 4, Char = e, Loc_rev: 18, Loc_forward 4
i = 5, Char = f, Loc_rev: 19, Loc_forward 5
i = 6, Char = g, Loc_rev: 20, Loc_forward 6
i = 7, Char = h, Loc_rev: 21, Loc_forward 7
i = 8, Char = i, Loc_rev: 22, Loc_forward 8
i = 9, Char = j, Loc_rev: 23, Loc_forward 9
i = 10, Char = t, Loc_rev: 10, Loc_forward 10
Returning at 10, s[i] = t
The first unique char is t

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated. This will do:

```
int in(char c, char *str) 
{
    while(*str != '\0') {
        if(*str == c)
            return 1;
        str++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char first(char *str)
{
    if(*str == '\0')
        return 0;
    else if(!in(*str, str+1))
        return *str;
    else return first(str+1);
}
```

`in` is a helper function that returns `1` if the string `str` contains the character `c`.

`first` will check if the first character is present in the string. If it is not, then we have found the first non-repeating character. If not, we do the same procedure, but start on the next character in the string.

Comment: But if I want to stick to my function, what is the problem there?

Comment: @sam0101 Why? This method is far better.

Comment: sorry I didnt mentioned that  the question is asking me to run through str just once and they already given me that the function need to be just with one argument